# Converting string array into int array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I working with a txt file, where some coordinates are stored in a script in this format:

```
[(310, 71), (466, 145), (432, 285), (238, 289), (196, 150)]
```

Initiating read file from another script, I need to get this input as integer, so that I can use it as input to make np.array.

But what I get is error, `''' invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[(310, 71), (466, 145), (432, 285), (238, 289), (196, 150)]' '''`

The code I am using to read and return is:

```
def function():
points = []
if (os.stat("file.txt").st_size!=0):
    print("Valid file found")
    with open('file.txt','r') as file:
        #points = []
        for line in file:
            points.append(line.strip())
else:
    print("No files found")

return points
```

This will return the points if the file is a valid one. And using inside the script:

```
x = function()
pts = np.array([x],np.int32)
```

So basically x will contain the value as string, and I need to convert them into same format to int, so that I can make it as input to some other.

Any help regarding this will be helpful and appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, when you read txt from a txt file or any file, the text is stored in a string format. So you would have to do some conversions :

```py
import re
def getList(text):
    someList = []
    text = re.sub(r"\s+", "", text, flags=re.UNICODE)
    for i in text[1:-2].split("),"):
        print(i)
        nums = i.split(",")
        print(nums)
        someList.append((int(nums[0][1:]),int(nums[1])))
    return someList
```

Pass The text read by your open file fn and pass it to this to get the List you want to pass to the `np.array([x],np.int32)` fn

Comment: thank you gentel man, with few more addition to your code, my snippet worked, i will add those lines below,  `x = getList(res)
arr=[]
for i in x:
 arr.append(i)`